# How to remove element from dictionary when removed from incoming JSON

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have server, what sending JSON data to client (C# - Unity3D) every tick (10/second) in this JSON format:

```
{ 
"bullets": {
  "123": {
    "x" : 1.23,
    "y": 23.4
  },
  "234": {
   same...
  }
  ...
}
```

What I have is that I add these bullets to Dictionary when they are not already in dictionary. When they are in dictionary, I just update xy positions.

I need one more thing what I dont know how to make. I need to remove all bullets what are not in JSON income already. It means, when bullet is removed on server, server just stop sending position of this bullet and client must remove it from his Dictionary (and from scene of course, but it isn't problem).

So there is some way how to achieve this without using server to send message to client, that bullet was removed? I mean, its just logical problem but I really don't know how to make it.

Comment: You can have a list of bullet that you get from the Dictionary Key (listA).

Then iterate the json to get the bullets, check for it in the listA and if it is there, move it to a new listB. If it is not there, add it to the new listB.

At the end, you have listA with a list of dead bullet, listB is the list of active bullets from server. 

You can then reconstruct your dictionary.

Comment: But I think that if number of bullets in dictionary is 'n' and number of bullets in JSON is 'm', I will get O(n*m). Its bad idea when I am doing this 10x in second (planned is 20x in second)

Comment: It would be O(m) as you only run the json dictionary. I just dont see why you store them. Just run and update. That's it. Particularly if removed ones are automatically taken care as you seem to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You parse your JSON and add all your bullets into ArrayList.
So you will have one list which you can say '**AllowedList**'.  Then you will add all key values in dictionary and finally remove those which are not present in AllowedList using **Enumerable.Except**

```
foreach (var key in MyDictionary.Keys.Except(AllowedList).ToList()){
            MyDictionary.Remove(key);
    }
```

The `ToList()` creates a new list of the set difference and prevents the exception. After this your dictionary will have only those entries which are on server.

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks bro. Just so out of speech: Is there some sort of easy way without Linq? Because I have locked in my brain, that Linq is slow and not doing good in games.